# Trying to pass a variable to a parameter in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How do I pass a variable to a parameter in Puppeteer.  My ultimate goal is to have multiple names (90+ names) for the pdf without having to type each file name

```
var name = example1

await page.pdf({
        path: '/name/.pdf',
        printBackground: true,
      });
```

Comment: Could you add more details about your code and what your goal is?

Comment: Maybe use an array and a loop? Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, (you can use string concatenation as well)

```
const names = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'];
for (const name of names) {
    await page.pdf({
        path: `/${name}.pdf`,
        printBackground: true,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want to open each URL and then save the web page as a PDF file. You can determine the filename/path based on the URL or webpage title, and then use the  method @digbijay-gautam to save the pdf file. Taking this page as an example, you can use the following filename/path:

```json
{
  "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744840/trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer",
  "basename": "trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "hostname_hashcode__MD5": "stackoverflow.com_981ce9411a44018e69819ca11425396b.pdf",
  "hostname_path_name": "stackoverflow.com_questions_77744840_trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "hostnameHashcode__MD5": "stackoverflow.com/981ce9411a44018e69819ca11425396b.pdf",
  "hostnameHashcode__SHA256": "stackoverflow.com/fb13fa83cab3939483467d20dcc953583ae7a9b4c334c6a409cdc799ecce4f53.pdf",
  "hostnamePath_name": "stackoverflow.com/questions_77744840_trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "hostnamePathname": "stackoverflow.com/questions/77744840/trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "hashcode__MD5": "981ce9411a44018e69819ca11425396b.pdf",
  "path_name": "questions_77744840_trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "pathname": "/questions/77744840/trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-parameter-in-puppeteer.pdf",
  "hostname_title": "stackoverflow.com_Trying to pass a variable to a parameter in Puppeteer - Stack Overflow.pdf",
  "hostnameTitle": "stackoverflow.com/Trying to pass a variable to a parameter in Puppeteer - Stack Overflow.pdf",
  "title": "Trying to pass a variable to a parameter in Puppeteer - Stack Overflow.pdf"
}
```